# New Cassandra nodes in cluster with different version

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-4.0

I have a Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes running on v3.11.4

I want to add 3 more nodes to this cluster. Now, Cassandra v4 is available so i have installed it on the new nodes.

When i restart Cassandra, the new nodes are unable to join the cluster.

**Error:** There are nodes in the cluster with a different schema version than us

I even tried added skip_schema options in jvm-server.options file but still the nodes could not join.

Please help me how can i add the new nodes in the existing cluster. I want to keep v4 for new nodes so i don't have to update these when upgrading older nodes to v4.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to add nodes running a new major version to the cluster. You will only be able to add nodes running Cassandra 3.11.

They won't be able to stream data to each other because they have different formats. This is the reason you can't run repairs during an upgrade. You also can't add or decommission nodes in the middle of an upgrade. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

So the plan forward here, would be to shut down the Cassandra 4.0 nodes.  Then upgrade the 3.11 nodes to 4.0.  Then adding the new 4.0 nodes should work as expected.